# Can someone explain to me why twisting effect on a body is proportional to perpendicular distance without using the concept of work?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque, spring

I understand that twisting must be proportional to perpendicular distance and force. If this was not the case conservation of energy would be violated.This is the explains  twisting effect on a body is proportional to perpendicular distance  from concept work.
 I want a answer which does not use concept of work to answer my question.
I do not want this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torque#Derivation. It uses power to derive torque.
I want to know about forces which act on individual particles even those from other particles in a rigid body when a body is rotating.
I want to know how does changing point of application of force change overall twisting effect produced in body.

Comment: Torque is not defined via energy.  Its definition is more fundamental and one can define work due to torque just like one does with force and distance.  Also, energy does NOT need to be conserved in the presence of torque.  What if the torque is due to friction, like in car brakes?  I think you need to rethink the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Could you possibly give a an example of the kind of physical system you have in mind?

Comment: You can't "derive torque", it is just a definition. Can you "derive" force?

Comment: For decades I derived the properties of torque (and rotational inertia),  in my classes, starting with work and Newton's second law.  That leads to a “definition” of torque as the work per unit angle of rotation that can be done by a force that might cause a rotation.  This reminds you that you need a component  of force in the direction of motion and a distance.  The questioner is looking for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment, so see [this](https://scholarship.haverford.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1494&context=physics_facpubs)

The Physical Origin of Torque and of the Rotational Second Law, Daniel J. Cross

Comment: Please, notice that link-only answers are not suitable for this site.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I meant to leave it as a comment but am unable due to my reputation. I may copy the derivation later if I have time, but I also do not care if anyone else wants to do it themselves.